# Determinar o maior numero primo apos ser fornecido um valor usando função while

Tags: python, while

Tenho que criar um exercicio para descobrir o maior numero primo apos ser me fornecido um certo valor usando a função while, o que esta errado no que criei abaixo??

```
def maior_primo(n):
    x=0
    y=0
    while y<=n:
        y=y+1
        x=n-1
        if (x % y==0 and x//y==0):
            return x
        else:
            x%y!=0
            return y
```

Comment: E você quer que a gente adivinhe qual é a  linguagem?

Comment: Python pela sintaxe

Comment: Isso não elimina o uso das tags xD

Comment: Claro, foi só numa de tentar adivinhar :D

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns problemas com a sua solução. O incremento no ciclo estava a ser feito logo no inicio por isso iria analisar um elemento a mais, em:

```
while y<=n:
    y=y+1
```

Para saber se um numero é primo temos de tentar dividir por todos os que estão no meio e não somente um, como acontece aqui:

```
if (x % y==0 and x//y==0):
    return x
```

Estendendo a sua solução e tornando correta:

```
def maior_primo(n):
    x=0
    y=n #começar do cima para baixo para poder sair no primeiro primo

    while y>=1: #ciclo agora ao contrario até 1
        for x in range(2, y + 1): #range nao inclui o ultimo, logo tem de ser y +1
            if y % x == 0:
                break

        if x == y: #se chegou até y é porque nao deu para dividir por nenhum, logo primo
            return x

        y = y - 1

    return 1 #se nao deu para achar nenhum primo retorna-se um
```